# Greedy algorithm compiles with no errors but never gets past first action when run

Tags: c, cs50, greedy

So I am taking cs50 and I am doing the greedy algorithm "cash" problem, and the code I've written compiles fine, but when I run it, it asks for "Change amount in USD:" and then never accepts a valid response and I'm stuck entering inputs forever and nothing happens.

A friend said that I was missing an input and that's why it wasn't working, but I'm trying to use the user's input, so... Your help would be greatly appreciated, because I think I'm really close, I just have not idea how to fix it, and help50 says that technically nothing's wrong, so I'm just at a stand still.

Thank you!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // identifying variables
float amount;
int cents;
int count = 0;

// prompting user for input
do
{
    amount = get_float("Change amount in USD: ");
}
// ensuring a positive number
while (amount < 0);

//changing float to an int
    cents = round(amount*100);

// using highest denomination first (quarters)
while (cents % 25 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents % 25;
}

// using next highest denomination second (dimes)
while (cents % 10 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents % 10;
}

// using next highest denomination third (nickels)
while (cents % 5 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents % 5;
}

// using last denomination amount (pennies)
while (cents % 1 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents % 1;
}

// displays number of coins used
printf("%i\n", count);
```

}

Comment: What input are you using to test the program?

Comment: I was instructed to use random positive and negative values to ensure that negative responses resulted in a re- ask and that a variety of positive numbers yielded the correct number of coins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are stuck in infinite loop since your logic is wrong. Take a look in a while loop, for example:

```c
while (cents % 25 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents % 25;
}
```

modules operation will give you a number between 0 and 24. The condition will always be true regardless of what cents original value was.

You want to update your condition to a different one. take notice that inside your while you should update cents differently, since after the first iteration cents values will not change: let's say it is 10. It enters the while loop, and then `cents=cents%25` will stay 10. Still infinite loop

Comment: Thank you! I can't say I entirely understand what you're saying but I think I mostly understand what you are saying. Does it have to do with the order at all? Is cents % 25 more or less viable than 25 % cents? I was looking through my notes again and thought maybe this had something to do with it.

Comment: What your code meant to do? Give as much change in quarters, then 10s and so on? (give the change in as less as possible coins)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (cents % 25 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents % 25;
}
```

The division willl always be `>= 0`, thus you have an infinite loop, switch to

```
while (cents % 25 > 0)
```

Comment: This change won't be enough since inside the loop he is only takes modules of the variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this bit of code (and those like it)

```c
// using highest denomination first (quarters)
while (cents % 25 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents % 25;
}
```

This will result in an infinite loop based on the principle that `any_integer_value % 25` is always `>= 0`. However, the problem actually doesn't require a mod operation at all. Instead, check if subtracting the coin's value is `>= 0` and if it is, do the subtraction.

```c
// using highest denomination first (quarters)
while (cents - 25 >= 0)
{
    count++;
    cents = cents - 25;
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm more of a word person than a number person. There is a principle that any integer value %25 will always be >= 0? Why would that be exactly?

Comment: Certainly! The `%` or the modulus operator returns the remainder of dividing the two numbers. The remainder is the number that's left over when you divide two whole numbers. If the number divides perfectly, the remainder is 0 because there's no left over. Therefore 0 is the minimum remainder because having a negative number left over doesn't make any sense. Also, the maximum is the number on the right minus one since if you add one more the number would divide evenly again, which means the remainder is 0. Therefore any number `%` any number is greater than or equal to 0, not just 25.